# Memory allocation in terms of paging

Tags: c, memory-management, linux-kernel, operating-system, kernel

In terms of paging, how exactly does memory allocation work? I understand how the buddy allocator, free list algorithm, etc. all work, but in terms of virtual memory and paging I am confused. For example, lets say I malloc 10 bytes. Lets say that there are 10 4kb virtual pages available. The OS uses one of these pages to allocate the 10 bytes. Would the OS mark this page as "not free" now? I am sure it does not do that, but how does it keep track that there are (4kb - 10 bytes) left in that page?

Answer (score 4):

Linux only works with pages.

*malloc* is a C library function. It's job is to allow allocation of arbitrarily-sized blocks of memory. It acquires/grows/shrinks pools of pages by using the *sbrk* or *mmap* kernel's facilities. It keeps track of the allocated and free bytes in the pools.

If a page was used to allocate some memory that is later freed the kernel has no way of knowing it is no longer needed, unless *malloc* tells it to release it (e.g. via *munmap*).

When *malloc* requests a page from the kernel a free virtual page in the process's virtual address space is marked as valid and returned. Access to an invalid page triggers a segfault.

Usually allocation is lazy. It means that no real page (i.e. backing store) is allocated at first. The first time the process writes to this virtual page a real page is allocated and the virtual page is pointed to it.

Then this real page might move back and forth between physical memory and swap space as needed.

Comment: +1, though a portion of the physical memory is usually called a frame to distinguish it from the virtual memory area (the page) that maps to it.

Comment: This is common OS textbook terminology. A virtual page points to a real page. The later is an abstraction that identifies a piece of data (the what) and points to the physical page (the where) currently containing this data. The advantage of this model is that keeping track of which piece of data a virtual page maps to (e.g. when cloning a process) is conceptually unrelated to keeping track of where that piece of data is stored (e.g. when swapping). An OS might use only two levels but the conceptual difference between what and where (the frame) remains and is easier to explain with this model.